# PowerShell code to copy Sql Server Reporting Services report security/permissions from one user to another

Tags: sql, powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I'm new to Powershell. But I need to find out whether it is possible to mimic a user's permissions on different SSRS reports (as some of these users have permissions to hundreds of reports) and grant these permissions to other AD users. I looked online, but haven't been able to find anything that can do that..yet. Was wondering if this is possible at all.

Comment: Are you using active directory groups for folder security?

Comment: Active Dir groups, yes.

Comment: I decided to create a stored proc that takes two parameters - the ID to be copied and the ID to be assigned permissions. And the stored proc returns a powershell function and the script to apply the permissions on the folders. So I copy and paste the results from the stored proc directly to powershell and it applies all the permissions to the ID. Not a one step solution but two.

Comment: Would you mind sharing that stored proc?  I need to do the same